# Cannot fill background of display cutout on landscape with desired color, looks ugly on Huawei

Tags: android, fullscreen, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I developed app and thought everything is right with full screen until I run it on huawei cloud debugging real devices and discovered it is not working there. I tried everything and don't see much about it anywhere.
It looks like I cannot get system bar space when running on landscape to disappear.[image]

I can see similar behaviour on all huawei phones.

My original approach was like this:

```
val window = activity().window
val controller = WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, view)
controller.systemBarsBehavior = BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
controller.hide(systemBars())
```

Then I started trying anything I found on SO.

Added to theme:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Before `setContentView` in `Activity` `onCreate` added:

```
activity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```

and bunch of other crazy or deprecated stuff like:

```
window.addFlags(FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
window.addFlags(FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN)
window.addFlags(FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
window.addFlags(FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN)

    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
        SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
```

Edit:
After some more evaluation it looks I actually have full screen right but that is "just" a space behind notch that for whatever reason doesn't match color of my application background.
So I was playing also with themes if I cannot change some background color so I will change color of that notch background space.

This are my styles that doesn effect notch:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/inst_surface</item>
<item name="colorSurface">?attr/inst_surface</item>
<item name="colorPrimary">?attr/inst_surface</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">?attr/inst_surface</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">?attr/inst_surface</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/inst_surface</item>
<item name="colorOnSurface">?attr/inst_text_strong</item>
<item name="colorSecondary">?attr/inst_control_active_foreground</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

I also tried this:

```
window.clearFlags(FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.addFlags(FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity(), cs_white);
```

Comment: Does it work on other devices?  If so, are you sure that device allows fullscreen an doesn't just show some parts of their UI regardless?

Answer (score 1):

So look like there is official solution for notches I was not aware and I have to implement it in theme.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout

Looks like in landscape you cannot color background when using landscape orientation so solution could be more work actually, I have to cover whole area adjust layout so I have desired color there.

So

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

is partly a solution but great amount of work is needed to make margin for any layout that needs it. Also as I understand notch can be on both sides so you have to use  `WindowInsetsCompat.getDisplayCutout()` to determine where it is and adjust layout to stay out of way in code. If anyone know easier solution would be nice.

Edit:

So top level final code looks like this:

```
onOrientationChange {
    navigation.view.updateLayoutParams<MarginLayoutParams> {
        leftMargin = displayCutout?.leftRect?.right ?: 0
        rightMargin = displayCutout?.rightRect?.width ?: 0
    }
}
```

Small explanation: onOrientationChange uses OrientationEventListener and defaultDisplay.rotation and also viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener to determine rotating of display, this was the hard part, then I just for now implemented it easily in top level of my application, looks pretty well now on simulator when testing display cutout using developer options.

[image]

[image]

I will release solution in my Renetik Android UI library.

Last thing to consider is to disable windowTranslucentStatus, windowTranslucentNavigation for api 26 otherwise it crashes :/ like this:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
```

in `values-v26` folder